# mapping nested field in mongo document with Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Spring data @Field doesn't support to flat object mapping of mongo nested document

```
 {
  "a" : 10,
  "b" : 11,
  "c" : {
    "d" : 12,
    "e" : 13
  }
}

class ZZ {

   @Field("a")
   int _a;

   @Field("b")
   int _b;

   @Field("c.d")
   int _d;

   @Field("c.e")
   int _e;
}
```

with a nested object hierarchy i am able to do it. I am looking for flat object solution?